# Register Helper functions Node.JS + Express

Tags: node.js, express, local-storage, helper

Im trying to learn NodeJS and Express. Im using the node-localstorage package to access the localstorage. This works when using the code directly in the function like this

***routes/social.js***

```
exports.index = function(req, res)
{
     if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) 
     {
        var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
        localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
     }

localStorage.setItem('myFirstKey', 'myFirstValue');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('myFirstKey'));
res.render('social/index', {title: "Start"});
}
```

But I don't want to write this code over and over again in all my other functions when accessing the localstorage. I want to be able to register a helper function that I can access like

```
 var localStorage = helpers.getLocalStorage
```

or something like that.

How can I do this in NodeJS? I've seen something about app.locals? But how can I access the app object in my routes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, depending on how/where you are planning to use your helper methods. I personally prefer to set my own node_modules folder, called `utils`, with all the helpers and utility methods I need.

For example, assuming the following project structure:

```
app.js
db.js
package.json
views/
   index.ejs
   ...
routes/
   index.js
   ...
node_modules/
   express/
   ...
```

Simply add a `utils` folder, under `node_modules`, with a `index.js` file containing:

```
function getLocalStorage(firstValue){
   if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) 
   {
      var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
      localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
   }
   localStorage.setItem('myFirstKey', 'myFirstValue');
   return localStorage;
}
exports.getLocalStorage = getLocalStorage;
```

Then, anytime you need this function, simply `require` the module `utils`:

```
var helpers = require('utils');
exports.index = function(req, res){
  localStorage = helpers.getLocalStorage('firstValue');
  res.render('social/index', {title: "Start"});
}
```

**EDIT**
As noted by **Sean** in the comments, this approach works as long as you name your node_modules folder with a name different from [Node's core modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules). This is because:

> Core modules are always preferentially loaded if their identifier is
>   passed to require(). For instance, require('http') will always return
>   the built in HTTP module, even if there is a file by that name.

Comment: Yes. I did something simillar:

`exports.getLocalStorage = function () {
  if (typeof localStorage === "undefined" || localStorage === null) 
 {
    var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;
    localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch');
  }
  return localStorage;
};`


Would you consider your way a "Best practise"? Im trying to learn Node/express and I want to do it "the right way" if you know what I mean.

Comment: Well, it really depends on what you are trying to do. I know that the "common wisdom" is to use a lib/ folder for common functionality when you have multiple apps (as advised by TJ Holowaychuk himself [here](http://vimeo.com/56166857)), yet, others prefer having [localized helpers](https://github.com/madhums/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo/tree/master/test). I prefer this method because I don't have to worry about the path to `utils` in the `require('utils')`(All other methods will use relative paths).

Comment: @varybadalloc: I've been given access to a Node project (Node is new to me) and notice that it already has: require('util') - that seems to be an existing Node package. There is no connection right? If so, I will just name my helper module differently for clarity.

Comment: @Sean the util you are referring to are core [node](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) modules. You should definitely rename your own helper module, since Node will always load the core module first, as stated [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules). This is actually a very good point, which would suggest that my solution is not good practise.